# Was there a downtime on StackOverflow? Days visited wrong

Tags: support

I saw there was a [scheduled database maintenance on Wednesday](https://www.stackstatus.net/), but there was no further update and no mentioning of a downtime. And since I was striving for the "Fanatic" badge and past the 50 day mark and suddenly I am back at 1 (or rather for a few minutes now 2) consecutive days. What's going on there?

Interestingly enough the problem appears to be limited to StackOverflow, not some of the other SE sites.

---

**Edit:** Well, I gave up for SO. If some glitch can trip me up like that after doing more than 50% and not just hitting refresh but voting, commenting and flagging, then there is no point. Let's see whether I can get it on other sites.

Comment: Have to ask - you know that the SO clock ticks over at UTC+0, right?

Comment: @Michael Petrotta: I didn't, but even better. I *live* at UTC+0 == GMT (and no, no DST here).

Comment: Then *go to bed already*!

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta: soon, not quite yet ;) ... holidays are jolly days.

Comment: Seems like it was either a conspiracy against you or that we're back to normal. Because it shows **77 consecutive** for me.

Comment: @hjpotter92: aaah, that would explain it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the logs, you spent most of the day on the new Reverse Engineering site. You did hit the homepage on SO, but didn't go any further than that.

Comment: Well, if you say so. Was very diligent about it, but then apparently the logs say I wasn't. Thanks for taking the time to look it up.

Comment: Wait! So your saying you can see _everything_ I do here?

Comment: here? no. *everywhere*, @Cole. and that color doesn't suit you at all...

Comment: But, but! It's my C++ shirt!

Answer (score 1):

I did not see any downtime and the visit counter looks ok -  I have **117 consecutive** now...

If there was any anomaly, it did not hit any majority of users...

Comment: I confirm it did not hit everybody. 1402 consecutive days here.

Comment: @AlexJ.: in the absence of someone from the team writing in answer, this is indeed a useful answer. +1. I guess I'll give up on that one. If it's not enough to visit and actively browse, vote, flag, comment, it's clearly beyond what I'm prepared to do.

Comment: To make your day count, you just need to go to your profile summary and hit refresh, thats all, see the number change. I think you must have missed a day or there was some other glitch, or your browser just showed you the cached webpage instead of refreshing. Its not that sophisticated to make your day count...

Comment: @Alex J.: as I mentioned on another answer, I am commenting, voting and flagging. So it's a bit disconcerting that suddenly a day should go missing, although I definitely visited (and did stuff) during the 24h period in question. Thanks for your remark.

Answer (score 1):

I think you must have just `Login` or to be more precise Just visited the [Home Page](https://stackoverflow.com/) and not done any activity like checking a question or visiting your profile,etc. In that case it won't be marked as **`visited`**.

I am answering this base on my experience, because even i am striving for the [Fanatic](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/enthusiast-and-fanatic-badges/) badge.

Comment: Uhm, nope. You think I only log in and do nothing else? In fact most of the days I don't even just browse but also read, vote, flag and comment.

Comment: In that case **I am Not sure** to why this happen. I just shared my **experience**.

Comment: thanks, and it's appreciated, don't worry :)

Comment: You do not have to do anything but refresh your profile to have "visited." But be careful whether your browser caches the page--hit reload *again*.